# Dell 8MM01 server won't start - flashing blue light

Tags: dell, startup, power-supply-unit

We have a DELL 8MM01 server that won't start-up. When we try to power it up an amber light slowly flashes at the back. When we push the button next to this light it changes to a flashing blue.

The server won't start-up... Any idea if these lights indicate the cause of the problem?

We think this may be a PSU issue as when we first tried to restart the server the PSU fan could be heard attempting to start spinning but then died.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure that you have the correct model number for your server, since there doesn't seem to be an "8MM01" listed on Dell's website.

If you can verify the server model or service tag # (may be on rear of server), you should be able to use the drill-down menus on the Dell support site to locate the correct service manual for your server.

It will tell you what the status lights & error codes mean.

Answer (score 2):

The light is a combination error\location\status light. Normally it should be solid blue. Pressing it and seeing it flashing blue allows you to locate it in your rack (from the rear) and flashing orange is an indication of an error state (PS, fan, memory, CPU, etc.). Is there an LCD display on front? If so, that should list the error code. You can take that code and look up it's meaning on the Dell support site, after you find the correct model number.

Answer (score 0):

8MM01 is a non existant model. The best course of action would be to actually call Dell support, and ask them to troubleshoot your machine. Even if its out of warranty, there usually isn't any problem with troubleshooting your server, and providing you with a diagnosis on what happened and what needs to be replaced